# Select dentro de where en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

La cuestión es que necesito introducir en un `where` condicional, según los datos que se envían al controlador, la cuestión una de esas condiciones es que me traiga los datos según un `select`, ya probé la consulta en el gestor de datos, pero en `laravel` supongo que se representa de otra forma, esto es lo que he intentado.

```
 $data = DB::table('historico_establecimientos')
                  ->where(function($data) use ($location,$anio,$mes)  {
                     if($location=="due") {
                         $data->where("anio_corte",$anio);
                         $data->where("mes_corte",$mes);
                     }else{
                         $data->where("anio_corte",('select MAX(anio_corte) from historico_establecimientos'));`introducir el código aquí`
                         $data->where("mes_corte",('select MAX(mes_corte) from historico_establecimientos'));
                     }
                  })
                  ->orderBy("nombre_establecimiento","ASC")
                  ->get();
```

Consulta `sql`

```
select * from historico_establecimientos where anio_corte  = (select 
MAX(anio_corte) from historico_establecimientos) and mes_corte = (select 
MAX(mes_corte) from historico_establecimientos)
```

Comment: Podrías compartirt la consulta en sql también?

Comment: Listo, está debajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar las [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions) de Laravel, así:

```
$data = DB::table('historico_establecimientos')
            ->where(
                'anio_corte', 
                DB::raw('(select MAX(anio_corte) from historico_establecimientos)')
            ->where(
                'mes_corte',
                DB::raw('(select MAX(mes_corte) from historico_establecimientos)')
            ->orderBy('nombre_establecimiento','ASC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Me aparece esto: {message: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded",…}

Comment: Intenta agregando esto dentro del `DB:raw(utf8_encode('select ...'))`

Comment: Gracias hermano, la consultaba estaba buena solo faltaba agregar los paréntesis dentro de valor del where.

Comment: Genial @AndrésCantillo, saludos!